# Material Sidenav overflows content if image is in sidenav

Tags: html, css, angular, material-design

Good morning!

I'm using a Material Design side navigation in my Angular app to offer page selection to the user. The side navigation contains a logo first and then all the pages the user can choose from - if he is logged in.

**Problem:**
If the user is not logged in, the logo is the element with the biggest width; and that confuses the positioning of the page content. The page content is overflowed by the sidenav, because the page content is aligend with the page links but not with the logo.

[image: The sidenav respects the width of the logo. The content does not]

As you can see the sidenav respects the width of the logo. The content does not.

**HTML:**

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-sidenav-container>
        <mat-sidenav #drawer mode="side" opened role="navigation">
            <mat-nav-list>
                <div class="logo-nav">
                    <img src="./assets/MyLogo.png">
                </div>
                <a id="nav-home" mat-list-item routerLink='home' routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
                <a id="nav-schulauswahl" mat-list-item routerLink='page1' routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="loggedIn">
                    Page 1
                </a>
                <a id="nav-schule-list" mat-list-item routerLink='page2' routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="loggedIn">
                    Page 2 with very long name
                </a>
                <a id="nav-logout" mat-list-item (click)='logout()' routerLinkActive="active">Logout</a>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-sidenav>

        <mat-sidenav-content>
            Some Content
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</mat-card>
```

**Typescript:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-sidenav',
    templateUrl: './sidenav.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sidenav.component.scss']
})
export class SidenavComponent {

    get loggedIn(): boolean {
        return true; // <- Toogle this to see all page links
    }
}
```

The core of the problem: The `margin-left` of `mat-sidenav-content` is calculated wrongly. As a workaround I hard coded it to 230px but this of course produces an ugly gap between sidenav and content if the user is not logged in:

**CSS:**

```
@import '../../styles/colors.scss';

.logo-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

// Workaround
mat-sidenav-content {
    margin-left: 230px !important;
}
```

[image]

If the user is logged in, then the longer page names appear which makes the `left-margin` being calculated correct.

[image]

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server? If yes please share link. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to fix this. For example:

1. Applying a `width` property to your logo image. Can be `100%` or `230px` as you have used.

```css
.logo-nav img {
  min-width: 230px;
}
```

2. Setting a `width` property to the sidenav itself. https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#setting-the-sidenav-39-s-size

```css
.mat-sidenav {
  width: 230px;
}
```

3. Changing the display of `mat-nav-list` to `flex` with `column` direction.

```css
.mat-nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all those options. I used the second one, due to another problem with material sidenav: When another option appears and the sidenav's width changes, the left-margin of mat-sidenav-content isn't immediatly recalculated - only after a page refresh. But a fixed width fo the sidenav is fine for my purposes.